# load a tree : ExtJs - Jayrock

Tags: extjs, tree, load, extjs4, jayrock

im trying to build a treepanel (or just a simple tree i just need it to work) and load it with data from database

here is my code to build the tree

```
  var objHandler = new Interact();

  var treestore = new  Ext.data.TreeStore ( {

     root:{
            id:'root_node',
            nodeType:'async',
            text:'Root'            
        },
     proxy:{            
            type:'ajax',            
            url:'myUrl'
        }


});     


    function ReadTree() {
            try {
                objHandler.ReadAssets(function (serverResponse) {
                    if (serverResponse.error == null) {
                        var result = serverResponse.result;

                        if (result.length > 2) {
                            treestore.load(Ext.decode(result));//TreeStore does not inherit from Ext.data.Store and thus does not have a loadData method. Both TreeStore and Store inherit from Ext.data.AbstractStore which defines a load method only. Therefore TreeStore has a load method
                           }
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(serverResponse.error.message);
                    }
                }); //eo serverResponse
            } //eo try
            catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        }




 var AssetTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Asset Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: treestore,
   // loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({    url: 'myurl'  }),

    columns: [
                { xtype: 'treecolumn',text : 'First Name',  dataIndex :'Title'}/*,
                {text : 'Last',  dataIndex :'Adress'},
                {text : 'Hired Month',  dataIndex :'Description'}*/
             ],
    autoscroll : true

}); 

     ReadTree();
```

im using jayrock : http://code.google.com/p/jayrock/

Interact.ashx.cs :

public class Interact : JsonRpcHandler
    {

```
    [JsonRpcMethod()]
    public string ReadAssets()
     {
        // Make calls to DB or your custom assembly in project and return the result in JSON format. //This part is making custom assembly calls.

        clsDBInteract objDBInteract = new clsDBInteract();
        string result;
        try
         {
            result = objDBInteract.FetchAssetsJSON();
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
         {
            throw ex;
         }
        return result;

     }
```

clsDBInteract.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Extensions;

namespace WebBrowser
{
    public class clsDBInteract
    {

        SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection("server=***********; user id = *****; password = ******; Database=*******");

        /////// data to fill assets grid
        public DataSet FetchAssetsDS()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
              {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select Title, adress, Description from table");
                sqlCommand.Connection = dbConn;
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                dbConn.Open();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                if (sqlCommand.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                    dbConn.Close();
                    }
                //ds = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
           catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 throw ex;
             }
          return ds;
       }//eo FetchAssetsDS

       public string FetchAssetsJSON()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
               {
                DataSet ds = FetchAssetsDS();
                result = ds.ToJSONString(); // This method will convert the contents on Dataset to JSON format;
               }
            catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 throw ex;
             }
            return result;
        }//eo FetchAssetsJSON




    }//eo clsDBInteract
}
```

I dont have any error, but the panel is empty, i tested and i can read the data in the readtree function..so i guess the problem would be in the store maybe or the loading

its been more than two weeks that im trying to pull this off
any help would be appreciated

*P.S: im using ExtJs4 with c# .net*

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this by creating my own type (no jayrock)

my tree model and store:

```
Ext.define('TreeModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        { name: 'text' },
        { name: 'id' },
        { name: 'descr' }

    ]
});

window.TreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: 'TreeModel',
root: Ext.decode(obj.TreeToJson()),
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax'
},
sorters: [{
    property: 'leaf',
    direction: 'ASC'
}, {
    property: 'text',
    direction: 'ASC'
}]
});
```

my class:

```
   public class TreeItem
{
    public string text { get; set; }

    public int id { get; set; }

    public string descr { get; set; }

    public string expanded { get; set; }

    public string leaf { get; set; }

    public List<TreeItem> children { get; set; }

}
```

then i get my data and fill my tree like this

```
public string TreeToJson()
    {  
List<TreeItem> child = new List<TreeItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            child.Add(new TreeItem() { text = t.AssetTree()[i].Item1, id = t.AssetTree()[i].Item2, ip = t.AssetTree()[i].Item3, descr = t.AssetTree()[i].Item4, expanded = "false", leaf = "true" });
        }

        TreeItem tree = new TreeItem() { text = "my root", id = 0, expanded = "true", leaf = "false", children = child };
}
```

hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

You havent given a `url` for the store to get the data from

```
proxy: {
        url:'myurl',
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }
```

I would recommend looking at the response in firebug to see if the data structure being returned is valid JSON

**EDIT**
This is how I would build the create the Tree assuming the JSON is valid for a tree (not just valid JSON)

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {   
    rootVisible:false,    
    store:Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {        
        root:{
            id:'root_node',
            nodeType:'async',
            text:'Root'            
        },
        proxy:{            
            type:'ajax',            
            url:'yourUrl'
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: dont worry about the type ,its only because i was trying to test with one field,but its corect in my code.

Comment: I verified in firebug..the data is ok

Comment: could you please explain to me how to add the url to the store?thank you

Comment: just add url:'myurl' in the proxy definition. Answer edited, hope this helps, keep us posted

Comment: thank you, added it  but it didnt change anything, i still dont have the data loaded in the tree

Comment: im also trying to make the treegrid example wrk for me but its not :((

Comment: anychance you can post the JSON thats being returned, then I might be able to help a little more. Ill edit my answer with how I would build the tree assuming the JSON is valid for a tree (not just valid JSON)

Comment: this is part of the json data (modified cause i cant post it,but the structure is as firebug return it) : 
id  1 
result
"[
{Title:'yahoo Website',adress:'www.yahoo.com',Description:'Serveur yahoo'},
{Title:'skype',adress:'skype.com',Description:'skype.com'},
{Title:'bing',adress:'www.bing.com',Description:'microsoft bing'},
{Title:'facebook',adress:'www.facebook.com',Description:'social network'},
{Title:'Google',adress:'http://www.Google.com',Description:'Google'},
{Title:'\' or 1=1--',adress:'\' or 1=1--',Description:'\' or 1=1--'}
]"

Comment: please explain to me how the url works i still dont get it, i know that its supposed to give the data to the tree,is it in json format?iam using two files : .cs and .ashx.cs to get the data from data base,stringify it then decode it to json format,i edited my question with more code,so should i add the url to the interact.ashx.cs ? ,thx a lot for ur help

Comment: ok, I have never used jayrock, but on the ExtJS side its irrelevant. The URL you provide will be the target of an AJAX call, and the data it returns is what is will use to build the tree. So if the JSON data returned is correct, the problem must lie with your EXTJS stuff.

Comment: ...just curious, you DO have a URL you can navigate to and see the JSON data...right?

Comment: no, the data is in my database not in a json file,so no i cant navigate to an url and see it

Comment: well you need some sort of method to get the data, it doesnt necessarily have to be in JSON format, check the ExtJS documentation. I personally find it easier to return a JSON string. How was firebug returning the JSON as you commented earlier?

Comment: i have a method that get the data from database, stringify it then decode i to json. why do u say it doesnt have to be injson format? if ts not it wont be recongnised..in fact i think my problem is the json format for tree,its not the one i have,because this method was first implemented to work with a grid,so now im looking to find a methode to decode to tree json format...or do u think it may be another problem?

Comment: json tree frmat should be like this http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/check-nodes.json