# Build and load a tree with data from database with ExtJs

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4

I'm trying to build a treepanel (or just a simple tree I just need it to work) and load it with data from database

I've been trying and trying and trying ..but cant do it.

Can someone show me how can I do this please?

My JSON:

```
{ 
    {Title:'yahoo Website',adress:'www.yahoo.com',Description:'Serveur yahoo'}, 
    {Title:'skype',adress:'skype.com',Description:'skype.com'},
    {Title:'bing',adress:'www.bing.com',Description:'microsoft bing'},
    {Title:'facebook',adress:'www.facebook.com',Description:'social network'},
    {Title:'Google',adress:'Google.com',Description:'Google';},
    {Title:'\' or 1=1--',adress:'\' or 1=1--',Description:'\' or 1=1--'} 
]
```

My C# code:

```
public class Interact : JsonRpcHandler {
    [JsonRpcMethod()]
    public string ReadAssets() { 
        clsDBInteract objDBInteract = new clsDBInteract(); 
        string result;
         try {
             result = objDBInteract.FetchAssetsJSON(); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
             throw ex;
        }
     return result; 
}
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Getting the data from the database? loading it into the tree?

Comment: loading it, see my previous topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952557/load-a-tree-extjs-jayrock/5986835#5986835
     but it seem that this method is not working for me so im looking if someone can point me to another one that works
       thanks

Comment: next time you provide more info on your question, remember to put it in your question and not the comment. It will help the community to easily understand you question and help you to get answer fast.

Comment: ok thank you for the edit..i do, just smetimes i delay a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this by creating my own type (no jayrock)

my tree model and store:

```
Ext.define('TreeModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        { name: 'text' },
        { name: 'id' },
        { name: 'descr' }

    ]
});

window.TreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: 'TreeModel',
root: Ext.decode(obj.TreeToJson()),
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax'
},
sorters: [{
    property: 'leaf',
    direction: 'ASC'
}, {
    property: 'text',
    direction: 'ASC'
}]
});
```

my class:

```
   public class TreeItem
{
    public string text { get; set; }

    public int id { get; set; }

    public string descr { get; set; }

    public string expanded { get; set; }

    public string leaf { get; set; }

    public List<TreeItem> children { get; set; }

}
```

then i get my data and fill my tree like this

```
public string TreeToJson()
    {  
List<TreeItem> child = new List<TreeItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            child.Add(new TreeItem() { text = t.AssetTree()[i].Item1, id = t.AssetTree()[i].Item2, ip = t.AssetTree()[i].Item3, descr = t.AssetTree()[i].Item4, expanded = "false", leaf = "true" });
        }

        TreeItem tree = new TreeItem() { text = "my root", id = 0, expanded = "true", leaf = "false", children = child };
}
```

hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

firstly look at [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/check-tree.html) simple example. This tree have a store wich can read infromation from url by json scructure. You can write there http://youdomain.com/yourscript.php. At yourscript.php you have to read information from database, encode it to JSON and run `echo your_json;` 
That's all.
P.S. [json example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/check-nodes.json)

Comment: thanks,i use c#  .net   ,  so what do i have to use instead f .php ?

Comment: same way. You have to make script for some url, read from db, encode to json, make resonse

Comment: i have been doinf this in an .ashx.cs file but when i put it in the url i get errors

Comment: Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode and invalid JSON String
           and sometimes i get this :             403 Forbidden
            see my previous topic for code :    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952557/load-a-tree-extjs-jayrock

Comment: i think i need something like echo myjsondata; but i dont know how to do add t to my function in c#..please bare with me im just begining in all of this..thank you

Comment: this s the data i see withe firebug  :   id 1 result "[ {Title:'yahoo Website',adress:'www.yahoo.com',Description:'Serveur yahoo'}, {Title:'skype',adress:'skype.com',Description:'skype.com'}, {Title:'bing',adress:'www.bing.com',Description:'microsoft bing'}, {Title:'facebook',adress:'www.facebook.com',Description:'social network'}, {Title:'Google',adress:'Google.com',Description:'Google';}, {Title:'\' or 1=1--',adress:'\' or 1=1--',Description:'\' or 1=1--'} ]"

Comment: this is my code :
public class Interact : JsonRpcHandler {

    [JsonRpcMethod()]
    public string ReadAssets()
     {
        
        clsDBInteract objDBInteract = new clsDBInteract();
        string result;
        try
         {
            result = objDBInteract.FetchAssetsJSON();
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
         {
            throw ex;
         }
        return result;

     }

Comment: @astrocybernaute first thing I notice, is that your json is not valid

Comment: this is incorect json for tree. It is look like json for grid. you have to generate json string manualy. look at  json example - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/check-nodes.json again

Comment: how do i generate json for tree?

Comment: with using strings methods. What did you want to see at tree by using your table from db?

Comment: i want th etree to display the data from my db,instead of displaying them in a grid, i need them tobe in a tree because they have ierarchie..is that ur question?